# Regex: how can I disallow a space after the end of a pattern?

Tags: regex

Problem:

Here is my pattern:
`173P` sometimes there could be an extra `173P` at the end; in that case I do not want continue.

How can I detect the the difference in simple regexp.

My attempt:
`/\A173P^ \z/`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: think you ,mean this `\A173P(?!\s)`

Comment: You got it. how about not just the space, also disallow , and ) after the pattern? Also, could you answer it so I can accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use anchors like this:

```
^173P$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/aT8zC9/2)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inverse character class to allow anything *except* a space character

```
[^ ]
```

Comment: so where would you put it in the main regex?